# Typescript Unions for object type

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to achieve something similar.

It is not possible to call someFunction in the if statement as key and value are used between the if statement and someFunction call.

```
type someObj = {
    a: string,
    b: number
};

type someObjType = { [K in keyof someObj]: { prop: K, value: someObj[K] } }[keyof someObj];

function someFunction(args: someObjType) {

};

function someOtherFunction() {
    let key: someObjType['prop'],
        value: someObjType['value'];
    if (Math.random() > .5) {
        key = 'a',
            value = 'some String'
    } else {
        key = 'b';
        value = 200
    };

    // Do Something using key and value.

    someFunction({ prop: key, value }) // throws an error.
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just go ahead and create an object of type `someObjType` in the `if` statement and then use `obj.prop` and `obj.value` instead of `key` and `value`?

```
function someOtherFunction() {
    let obj: someObjType;
    if (Math.random() > .5) {
        obj = {
            prop: 'a',
            value: 'some String'
        };
    } else {
        obj = {
            prop: 'b',
            value: 200
        };
    };

    // Do Something using obj.prop and obj.value.

    someFunction(obj)
};
```

Comment: This is what i ended up doing. Thanks anyway.